# How to get list of added files from TortoiseSVN post-update hook

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-hooks, post-update

I would like to write Tortoise SVN post-update hook script on client side. TSVN transfers following parameters: path/to/pathsfile, depth, revision, path/to/errorFile, path/to/CWD. I can get all changed added and etc. files using first parameter, but I can't get statuses of this files (Updated, Added, Deleted, etc). Please, help, how can I do that?

```
//code is very simple:)
var objArgs = WScript.Arguments;
var paths = readPaths(objArgs(0)); /*objArgs[0] - path to TSVN temp file which contains all the paths for svn update operation. Here I would like to get list of files which will be added in the working directory after update operation*/

command = "mvn help:effective-settings"
wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oExec = wshShell.Exec("cmd /c " + command);

var output = "";
if (!oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream) {
    output = oExec.StdOut.ReadAll();
}
output = output.replace(new RegExp("\r*\n+", "g"), "");
//getting credentials for connecting to database
var uid = //getting userId
var password = //getting password
//next step - deploying added in a working copy files, but it doesn't matter


function readPaths(path) {
    var retPaths = [];
    var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    if (fs.FileExists(path)) {
        var a = fs.OpenTextFile(path, 1);
        while (!a.AtEndOfStream) {
            var line = a.ReadLine();
            retPaths.push(line);
        }
        a.Close();
    }
    return retPaths;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of the hook script that you've got so far please? That should make things a lot easier.
EDIT: Probably worth changing any URLs contained in there before you paste it in :)

Comment: Yes, I can)) but in my opinion this is unlikely to help

Comment: It looks like you can't get that information from the parameters passed during the update. The only way you can get that information afaics is to use `svn log -v` - possibly passing the HEAD revision as the argument and maybe even the filename (though `svn log -v -r HEAD` will show you all the changes as of the latest commit, so that'd probably be easier than running `svn log -v *filename*` based on the files you get listed from your hook script).

I think you'll have to call that command from within the hook script to get what you need.